# Issue in getting device token of android using gcm

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, devicetoken

I can not get my device token and i am using the GCMRegistrar
I am giving my codes . What is wrong with me i can not understand.

my Manifest file includes

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.example.apnsautodial" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
     <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
```

my activity includes

```
GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);       
regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
if (regId.equals("")) {
    GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
}
```

Please help me out

Thanks in adv

Answer (score 1):

there is nothing wrong with your "myActivity".But in order to get registration id you need to add permission to connect with internet in your app so that your app can make request and get id from GCM server.

Add below lines in your Manifest file .Hope it will solve your problem.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Please Visit this link :http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html to get clear idea.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best example you can use using Google Cloud Messaging Api as per old GCM library methods are deprecated now, 
[Google Cloud Messaging](http://javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications/)

you can refer this,
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html